# Why does WKWebView delegate not exist?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, wkwebview

I am setting up a bridge javascript -> iOS with `WKWebView`. `UIWebView` did have a `delegate`, but `WKWebView` didn't? Why, how? I want to implement `didReceiveScriptMessage` method. How can I indicate, that method is implemented in self?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [`WKScriptMessageHandler`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKScriptMessageHandler_Ref/). Here is some more info on how to use it...

http://www.joshuakehn.com/2014/10/29/using-javascript-with-wkwebview-in-ios-8.html